# The github pages blog can upload but cannot display the content

Tags: github, hexo

I have a github.io blog which can display very well before. But recently when I added a new articles and pushed it to github(by "hexo generate" and "hexo deploy"), I found that there isn't any contet words on my blog. In github blog repository ((https://github.com/zwdnet/zwdnet.github.io) I can see the pages pushed successfully. And when I check the blog's source code in my brower, I can see the newest article. My blog url is: https://zwdnet.github.io/ It is a Chinese blog. I can visit other github.io blogs, so maybe this is not the network problem. How can I solve this problem? Reseting the github pages? Thanks for any helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening your website, according to the console errors. Your blog is missing the JQuery `$` library.

[image]

Check the header part of your code, add in a JQuery link will fix this problem.

Add this in the header tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This maybe the key problem. I solved it by updating hexo.         
1."npm i hexo-cli -g" 2."npm install -g npm-check" and "npm-check" 3."npm install -g npm-upgrade" and "npm-upgrade" 4. "npm update -g" and "npm update --save"                                The reference sites is : https://www.jianshu.com/p/802182c01b59